Is this a valid approach to password reset
I'm currently building a password reset flow and wanted to check this made sense.
So the user would make a request passing their email which would generate a token, this would be sent to the user and stored hashed. I have not salted it as I would imagine a 32 byte random string with a 30 min life would be borderline impossible and not a viable attack vector. (Live read access would also be required).
const error = validate(email, isEmail);
const resetToken = require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

// TODO send token link via email

const hashedToken = crypto
  .pbkdf2Sync(resetToken, '', 10000, 64, 'sha512')
  .toString('hex');

const thirtyMins = dayjs().add(30, 'minute').toDate();
return (
  error ??
  db('user').where('email', email).update({
    reset_token: hashedToken,
    reset_token_expiry: thirtyMins,
  })
);

They would then visit a page to enter the email again, and a password (with confirm), this form would also have the token from a query param inserted as a hidden field. This would call and endpoint to reset which would run this code.
const user = await User.getByEmail(req.body.email).catch((e) => next(e));

if (!user) {
  return res.redirect(
    '/update-password?error=Password could not be updated'
  );
}

const hashedToken = crypto
  .pbkdf2Sync(req.body.token, '', 10000, 64, 'sha512')
  .toString('hex');
if (hashedToken !== user['reset_token']) {
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Invalid token');
}

if (dayjs().isAfter(user['reset_token_expiry'])) {
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Token expired');
}

const { salt, hash } = genPassword(req.body.password);

User.updatePassword({
  hash: hash,
  salt: salt,
  resetToken: req.body.token,
  email: req.body.email,
})

Thanks in advance for any help

The general process looks good. I would make two changes tho:

I would encrypt the token before sending it to the user by email and skip the hashing
I would move the expiration check before performing the decryption
In the code provided, you are not doing anything with error
Generally, is better to unload to a variable and not use req.body attributes directly

const email = req.body.email
const error = validate(email, isEmail);
if(error)
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Email is not valid')

// generate original token
const crypto = require('crypto')
const reset_token = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex') 

//encrypt token
const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
const secret_key = 'your 24 hex char secret key'
const iv = 'your 16 hex char secret initialization vector'
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)

let encrypted_token = cipher.update(reset_token, 'utf8', 'hex')
encrypted_token += cipher.final('hex')

// TODO send token link via email with encrypted_token

// set expiration and store original token
const thirtyMins = dayjs().add(30, 'minute').toDate()
return (
  error ??
  db('user').where('email', email).update({
    reset_token,
    reset_token_expiry: thirtyMins,
  })
)

// validate token presence
if(!req.body.token)
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Invalid token')
// validate email
const error = validate(email, isEmail);
if(error)
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Email is not valid')
// validate user exists
const email = req.body.email
const user = await User.getByEmail(email).catch((e) => next(e))
if (!user)
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Password could not be updated')

// validate token not expired
if (dayjs().isAfter(user['reset_token_expiry']))
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Token expired')

//decrypt token
const token = req.body.token
const crypto = require('crypto')
const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc'
const secret_key = 'your 24 hex char secret key'
const iv = 'your 16 hex char secret initialization vector'
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, secret_key, iv)
let decrypted_token

try{
decrypted_token = decipher.update(token, 'hex', 'utf8')
decrypted_token += decipher.final('utf8')
} catch(e){
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Token malformed')
}

// validate original token matches
if (decrypted_token !== user['reset_token']) 
  return res.redirect('/update-password?error=Invalid token')

// perform password update
const password = req.body.password
const { salt, hash } = genPassword(password)

User.updatePassword({
  hash: hash,
  salt: salt,
  resetToken: req.body.token,
  email: req.body.email,
})


Amazing thanks will implement those changes!
I don't think I can send the encrypted token though as then the user would have no way to provide the token.

Sending an encrypted token is better because the server has to decrypt the token in order to see if the original text matches.
This means the user cant send just a random thing you would have to hash to test against your database. With the previous version, you could get a DoS attack where user send a lot of tokens leveraging the amount of time needed to hash it.
Because the decryption would fail if the token is malformed, less resources are used.
Just remember you have to decrypt whatever the user provides before comparing the  original text stored in the database.

Hey! Thanks for responding!
I might be missing something but wouldn't that invalidate the benefit of encrypting the token? If you have access to the db read you could calculate the hashed token which would not be the case if the non-encrypted token was sent.
I'm not sure on the DoS risk, need to look into that for sure but wouldn't the login form pose the same risk?

If you send the random string randomBytes(32).toString('hex')  as a token, an attacker only has to guess 32 characters. Also an atacker has a window in which it can send you brute-forced 32 character strings, strings that you will have to hash and compare in order to tell if they are correct or not. This hashing results in computational cost that could lead to a DoS because the memory will run out for example.

If you send an encrypted string, is highly improbable the attacker would be able to brute-force a string that will succeed the decryption since you are encrypting using a secret algorithm, a secret key string, and a secret initialization vector string.
If by some miracle the attacker manages to brute-force a decryptable string during the time window, the attacker would also have to make sure the decrypted output matches the randomly generated string that is stored in the database. Additionally, you would not use as many resources since most attacks would fail in the decryption attempt.
